# How to make two tables be shown with inline style?

Tags: html, css

I want to show 2 table inline, so i have tried to set its display to inline. It fails :(

What is the simplest way to set them to be shown inline?

```css
table {
  display: inline;
}
table, td, th {
   border: 1px solid black;
   }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Lois</td>
    <td>Griffin</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Lois</td>
    <td>Griffin</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This is working

Comment: @Weedoze sorry, i miss my border style in the above code..

Comment: Not sure what you're expecting, but your example doest what is expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `display:inline-table`.

[**MDN Reference**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display)

> The inline-table value does not have a direct mapping in HTML. It behaves like a  HTML element, but as an inline box, rather than a block-level box. Inside the table box is a block-level context.

```css
table {
  display: inline-table;
}
table,
td,
th {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Lois</td>
    <td>Griffin</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Lois</td>
    <td>Griffin</td>
  </tr>
</table>


<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Lois</td>
    <td>Griffin</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this.
If you want 2 table in inline style, then you have to take outer table first. And in that table's `<td>` you can take inner tables `<table>`.

```
<table width="1000">
<tr>
<td>
<table border="1" width="500">
    <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Lois</td>
    <td>Griffin</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</td>
<td>
<table border="1" width="500">
    <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Lois</td>
    <td>Griffin</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -2):

If you are using bootstrap, please try to utilize the column structure.

If not use table try **float** property.

```
  table {
    float: left;
  }
```

[here is an sample code in fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/SatheeshMallow/5euavv2b/)

Comment: i cannot using float, it will destroy my real web page.. and i am not using bootstrap

Comment: You can try to use nested table method. It may not affect anything